# Can a mobile user update a location's (custom) fields?

Tags: commcare

I added several custom fields to my locations (organizations) hierarchy. These get pulled into hidden values in certain forms in order to be included on data exports.

Each mobile user is assigned to multiple organizations. I have an "Edit form" that lets them edit certain information about each of their assigned organizations (e.g. if the contact phone number changes). This edits the organization's case properties.

**My question is: is it possible for a mobile user to edit one of these custom location fields? Or can it only be modified by web users?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom location fields cannot be updated by a CommCare application. If you need to have data that is associated with mobile workers that is editable, you could use the User Case, or like you noted you can add/modify properties on the organization's case.